# Why does sbt fail to find KafkaUtils?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, sbt, spark-streaming

I have this error in my code (wordCount from Kafka) compiled with SBT

```
[error] /home/hduser/sbt_project/project1/src/main/scala/sparkKafka.scala:4:35:            object kafka is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming`
[error] import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
 not found: value KafkaUtils
[error] val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-stream           ing-consumer-group", Map("customer" -> 2))
```

The file `build.sbt` contains these dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.12" % "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12" % "2.4.0"
```

How can I correctly import `KafkaUtils`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KafkaUtils` is in the `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010` package (note that the namespace for the import includes the version `kafka010`).

From [Spark Streaming Kafka Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html):

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
// ...

// val streamingContext = ...

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
```

Note: It's usually recommended to use [Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks.
But in the line 
`val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]`

What I insert in place of **String**?

`val lines= KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[000.000.000.000:2181, String]`

In this way I have 2 error

Comment: Nothing... Those are the key and value types, which correspond to the `classOf[StringDeserializer]`... You get errors because you changed it. If your topic has strings for keys and values, then this code works as-is. The only thing you need is the `streamingContext`. And again, do not use `:2181` to connect to Kafka

Comment: Thanks but I still have error:

`......[error]  cannot be applied to (String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object])
[error]   Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 14, 2019 1:30:35 PM`

I copied the code from [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot tell what the `^` arrow is pointing at, but I assume there is something you've written before that line, that is causing the problem. Please edit the initial question to format the full error, and your new code. However, I think it would be better to post a new question, because I think we've solved your KafkaUtils class not being found.