# Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration 0.8.2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have problems integrating spark with kafka. I using spark-streaming-kafka-0-8. I compile with SBT.
This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
object sparkKafka {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]")

        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

        val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,
    "localhost:2181", "spark stream",  Map("customer" -> 2))

        kafkaStream.print()
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

I received this error:

```
`[info] Running sparkKafka
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.<init>(SparkConf.scala:723)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:571)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:92)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:81)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setAppName(SparkConf.scala:118)
[error]         at sparkKafka$.main(sparkKafka.scala:15)
[error]         at sparkKafka.main(sparkKafka.scala)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.<init>(SparkConf.scala:723)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:571)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:92)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:81)
[error]         at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setAppName(SparkConf.scala:118)
[error]         at sparkKafka$.main(sparkKafka.scala:15)
[error]         at sparkKafka.main(sparkKafka.scala)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [error]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Jan 14, 2019 2:19:15 PM.`
```

This is my build.sbt file:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % "2.2.0"`

How can I interated spark streaming with Kafka? I have a problem even spark-streaming-kafka-0-10....

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498035/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-scala-productclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version issue with Scala or Spark. Make sure you first are using Scala `2.11`

If you are using Kafka 0.10, or higher (which if you've setup Kafka recently, and are only running it locally, then you likely would be), then you shouldn't be using `kafka-0-8` package.

Do not mix `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8` with `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10`

So, if you wanted to use `0-10`, [as answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153116/why-does-sbt-fail-to-find-kafkautils), the package needs to be `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010`, not `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka`

Also, note that the `0-8` does use Zookeeper (`localhost:2181`, for example), and `0-10` does not.